# Memory location different when attempting to redefine private variable in class

Tags: c++

I define a simple `Class obj` with a private variable `a` instantiated inside of it privately. I defined a default constructor to initialize the variable to 0. I also define a secondary constructor which initializes the variable `a` to the number that I pass to the secondary constructor. Thus, I do the following:

```
using namespace std;

Class obj{
   int a;
public:
   obj(){
      a=0;
   }
   obj(int b){
      a=b;
   }
}

int main(){
   obj foo;
   //some inner scope 
   {
   obj foo(1);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have attempted to "redefine" the class `object` with the same name later on in the code.

Here is my issue. This works, but not as I expected it to: the variable `a` is actually defined twice, with the same name, but are stored in two different memory addresses, and I do not understand why. Is it not possible to redefine a variable in c++ at the same memory address generally speaking? Or is this a particular issue with classes and privately defined variables?

EDIT:

In fact I had a misunderstanding about scopes in c++ and the way in which my question was initially phrased was not entirely accurate. The way I was redefining the variable was actually inside of some inner scope and thus would automatically be removed once the scope ended. So I thought that the same variable was being defined twice, existing simultaneously, located at different locations in the memory. But in fact the value I wished to recall later on in the code had been deleted since the inner scope had come to an end.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Creating another object with the same name in an inner scope, or somewhere else entirely, does nothing about an existing object with the same name. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: The language would be unusable if you had to know ever other variable name used by every other piece of code that might possibly be linked with yours to ensure you didn't wind up accessing and modifying some other piece of code's variables.

Comment: So if I declare a `Class obj` and then another few lines later declare `Class obj`, they are actually two different objects stored in two different locations in memory? so if I use `obj` somewhere below, its a toss up as to which one I am actually calling upon?

Comment: @ChristinaS: That all depends on what is between those two lines. C++ has scoping rules for names in different scopes. It's never a toss-up as to what happens though; C++ spells out when it is allowed, when it isn't, and what the meaning of it is when it is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it not possible to redefine a variable in c++ at the same memory address

It is not possible to "define a variable at"  any memory address. You define a variable, and the language implementation takes care of picking the address where the object is stored (if the variable names an object).

One variable *can* have the same address as another variable, as long as the lifetime of those variables does not overlap. The requirement is necessary because the address of all objects is unique for the duration of their lifetime. There are exceptions to this when it comes to sub objects, for example member variables can share the address of the super object.

> Or is this a particular issue with classes and privately defined variables?

No. You'll find that this works the same regardless of the access specifier, and also to objects of all types in general, not just classes.

> So if I declare a Class obj and then another few lines later declare Class obj, they are actually two different objects stored in two different locations in memory?

Every *definition* of a variable is an individual object. Static namespace scope variable declarations can declare one object multiple times.

Comment: Thank you. then is it possible to call "different instances" of "different variables" with the same name? as in obj1 is stored at mem address A and obj1 (second instance) is stored at mem address B: may I somehow simply call the information stored at each mem address?